# How can I share local database of an existing app with a new app and make both work on it simultaneously?

Tags: database, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net, data-sharing, shared-data

One of my client's inventory management project supports online as well as offline mode to manage huge inventory data and is built using Xamarin.Forms & sqlite-net. Now, the client wants to create another similar kind of app and wants us to use the same local db of the first app.

The actual functionality he needs is that if I have data in one app then it can be shared to the second app and vice-versa. Like, if I'm logged into the first app then user automatically gets logged in to second app when it is launched. For that reason being, we need to have a shared database among both these apps. So, that both apps can read and write in a shared database. How can I achieve this? What will be the best and most efficient approach in Xamarin?

After some research I've found things like shreduserid for data sharing among android apps and App Groups for data sharing for iOS app. If anyone can help me with how to work around with them and best approach to follow.

Anyone having any idea or have done such thing is requested to provide your suggestions/links/code etc.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's a good solution to share local data between apps. There are big limitations to share data between apps in iOS. I would recommend you to save the data on the server side.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Can you please address those limitations for me? As my client requires this functionality.

Comment: I never did this before and it's hard to transfer lots of data at real-time. And maybe you can find a way to make one of your app work as a sever.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I'm going for the same approach by making a separate service app, that both my applications can access and use to share a centralised database. Do you have any experience or suggestion for the same?

Comment: Actually, I don't have any experience on doing this.

Comment: Ok thanks @JackHua-MSFT