# Share local offline cache between two Firestore apps of same project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two apps that use the same Firebase project, so they use the same database when online.

I would like to know if there is some way to make them also share their offline data. In other words, if I make an offline write on app A, I would like to be able to read that document on app B while still offline (metadata pending write = true).

Perhaps if there was a way to change the Firestore local database location to a shared location for both apps, this could be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps (on iOS, Android, and Web) work in a sandboxed environment, and access to each other's sandbox is highly controlled. While it may technically possible to build a solution that shared the local cache, the Firebase SDKs in each app currently uses its own sandbox for its local cache and these can't be shared.

Also see:

- [How can I share local database of an existing app with a new app and make both work on it simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55546362/how-can-i-share-local-database-of-an-existing-app-with-a-new-app-and-make-both-w)

Comment: This is what I suspected, thank you for your authoritative answer.